# Why has this question been deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I am really curious as to why this question was deleted:

[Jquery Ajax do not wait for response (callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984947/jquery-ajax-do-not-wait-for-response-callback)

Answer (score 6):

The user requested deletion himself:

> Okay i was wrong. It has something todo with the php session. If i disable cookies it works fine. Just flagged it for deletion. Sorry

Comment: ok fine! that question was quite legitimate IMHO. His code was wrong in the first place. But if he deleted it... Well I'll just have to cope with my 8 reputation loss! thanks (8 is a lot for me!)

Comment: @Jmorvan but you've gotten +15 MSO rep... and thats... well... MSO rep!

Comment: @Jmorvan do consider (and I say this with some trepidation) that if you can create a SSCCE (or [MCVe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215383/213963)) that describes the problem you were solving and the solution to it **well** you could ask and answer it yourself.  (trepidation: not a dup, written well, not contrived example...)  That said, you *have* done it before successfully.

Comment: thanks @MichaelT! But I am not "that" much in need for reputation! I have indeed replied to a lot of my own questions! I trepidate with you!

Comment: @Jmorvan a deleted question should be treated as if the question never existed in the first place. You can't lose rep from this event, only go up and then back down the same amount.

Comment: its not really for the rep! its more the loss of time really that bothers me!

Comment: In principle, allowing users to delete their own questions violates the notion of sharing and turns the site into a private Q&A site. Once there are responses, only moderators should be able to delete a question. The loss of rep earned means that respondents lose what little reward they receive for their efforts. And it would appear from what's visible to the SO peasantry that the question was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Magoo that's why users can't normally delete their questions once they have a response with at least one upvote. This seems to have been a special case because the OP realized they had made a mistake

Comment: @Pëkka I believe the significant part is this : `If i disable cookies it works fine.` This is knowledge that someone else could use to solve a similar problem - but can't because the question has been deleted. I'd say that it should be undeleted, but I've had bad experiences with mods re-deleting apparently (with no reason given) on a simple matter of opinion. If OP simply sweats on the little red circ - I mean, square to appear, then they can apparently delete a question before anyone has both the opportunity and inclination to vote a response up.

Comment: @Magoo there are many good reasons to allow a user to withdraw their question during the first couple of minutes, though. I agree with you in general, but the current rule seems like a good compromise. I agree a case could be made to undelete that question